# Custom Accordion Component not rendering body elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have a collapse/accordion component from Antd that I customized and exported from an elements folder from within my application so that I could reuse it across the app.

When I import it and include it inside another component I can't render any of the body elements inside. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and if there's a way around it?

Also as a smaller side issue when the body of the accordion opens to display, the whitespace doesn't fill the entire container and it looks like there's a grey column running down the right side.

I've included a code sandbox here to better show what I mean

[image: Edit Q-56776002-Wrong-Import]

## Custom Collapse Component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Collapse as AntCollapse } from "antd";

const StyledCollapse = styled(AntCollapse)`
  &&& {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
`;

const CustomCollapse = props => {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
  return (
    <StyledCollapse onChange={() => setDisabled(prev => !prev)}>
      <AntCollapse.Panel
        header={props.header}
        key="1"
        showArrow={false}
        bordered={false}
        extra={<p style={{ color: "#0076de" }}>{disabled ? "SHOW" : "HIDE"}</p>}
      />
    </StyledCollapse>
  );
};

export default CustomCollapse;
```

## Main Component

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";

import AntCollapse from "./CustomCollapse";

const Flexbox = styled.div`
  font-family: sans-serif;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: solid 1px palevioletred;
  padding: 10%;
  margin: 10%;
`;

const ConfigurationOptions = () => (
  <Flexbox>
    <AntCollapse header="configuration test">
      <h1>Test</h1>
      <p>Test Paragraph</p>
      <p>Test Paragraph</p>
    </AntCollapse>
  </Flexbox>
);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<ConfigurationOptions />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to pass down the children in your custom collapse component.

To get it to work, do this:

```
const CustomCollapse = props => {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
  return (
    <StyledCollapse onChange={() => setDisabled(prev => !prev)}>
      <AntCollapse.Panel
        header={props.header}
        key="1"
        showArrow={false}
        bordered={false}
        extra={<p style={{ color: "#0076de" }}>{disabled ? "SHOW" : "HIDE"}</p>}
      >
        {props.children}
      </AntCollapse.Panel>
    </StyledCollapse>
  );
};
```

(also to get the weird grey side column off the side you should do it like this:

```
const CustomCollapse = props => {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
  return (
    <StyledCollapse onChange={() => setDisabled(prev => !prev)}>
      <AntCollapse.Panel
        header={
          <span>
            {props.header}
            <span style={{ color: "#0076de", float: "right" }}>
              {disabled ? "SHOW" : "HIDE"}
            </span>
          </span>
        }
        key="1"
        showArrow={false}
        bordered={false}
      >
        {props.children}
      </AntCollapse.Panel>
    </StyledCollapse>
  );
};
```

)

Comment: That did it thank you! Any idea on how to fix the weird grey column to the right of the body?

Comment: sure, I added the answer to that to my main answer (second half)